# CardLayout Issues

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have this main window that extends a JFrame which flips a lot of different JPanel's, so I thought the CardLayout would be useful for this kind of behavior.

I've added two panes in the CardLayout, one pane is way bigger than the other, when I added both panes, the first one which is smaller was shown, while the second which is bigger wasn't(Good behavior), but it left a huge space below of the first pane.

I don't know how the size works on the CardLayout, but It doesn't respond to pack(), looks like it uses a specific algorithm to figure out the preferred size for the layout.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3):

`CardLayout` allows the GUI to `pack()` to the size of the **largest** card.

You might 'arrange white-space in a visually pleasing manner' for the smaller cards, and put the larger cards into scroll-panes.

> The first pane is a login form

I'd show that in a `JOptionPane` (e.g. as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773412/418556) - screenshot below) or a modal `JDialog`.

[image]

Comment: The first pane is a login form, while the second one contains 4 calendars and many fields, if I put the second pane in a scrollView will this set the maximum height to the smaller pane?

Comment: Hmm well, I think we could argue on how we could implement visually speaking, the login pane. I find it more appealing to have everything incorporated within the main window. Besides, I have multiple Panes and I find the CardLayout very useful to switch between different views. I haven't had the change to try the scroll bar, but I will have to do it before the end of the week so I will keep you updated.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, the other components might logically fit well in a single `CardLayout`.  It is just that I'm most used to seeing ('the path of least surprise') a log-in in a separate (modal) pop-up.  A web-app would be different - you'd tend to keep it all contained in the one page.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: +1 Agree, but limiting [_modality_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28computer_interface%29) is also a useful goal. [SquirrlSQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is an example.

Comment: @trashgod I like quasimodes. No, wait ..that's Quasimodo I'm thinking of. :)  Thanks for the links.