# JOptionPane with multiple inputs on different lines

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, joptionpane

I'd like to create a `JOptionPane` that allows a user to select an IP address and port to connect to. It should be structured as such,

> IP Address: [textfield here]
>
> Port: [textfield here]
>
> Cancel OK

The labels should be aligned to the left, and the textfields should be left aligned too. I can't really model the storyboard here, but basically the textfields shouldn't be misaligned, even if there is a space between the labels and the textfields.

Each label and textfield pair should be on seperate lines, and the Cancel OK buttons should be aligned to the right, below the textboxes.

Is there any way to do this in code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @user1329572 I've tried code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555040/multiple-input-in-joptionpane-showinputdialog) but this puts all the fields in the same row, and misaligns the Cancel and OK buttons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773412/418556) that seems similar in layout.

[image]

### The example

#### Right align

Right aligns the text in the labels, which I think looks better, using this:

```
labels.add(new JLabel("User Name", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
```

For left aligned text, change it to:

```
labels.add(new JLabel("User Name"));
```

#### Improvement

It is done using a nested layout, `GridLayout` instances in the `WEST` and `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`.

It might be better done using a more powerful layout such as `MigLayout` or more modern J2SE layout such as `BoxLayout` or `GroupLayout`.

`GroupLayout` can provide the type of alignment this UI needs, while not stretching the `CENTER` fields to the same width (which is also fixable in a nested layout as above, but requires 2 more constraining panels).  I believe the other two could do the job as well, but don't have as much experience with them.

Comment: I always knew you had this example :-), just couldn't find that in my search +1 for this

Comment: @nIcEcOw (chuckle) Only reason I could find it in a search, was because it is recent.

Comment: @mKorbel  Just trying to save the e-planet.  No electrons were harmed in the making of this message (though some were mildly inconvenienced).

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom dialog (jdialog) or use JOptionPane.showInputDialog, see this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html