# Unfocus on all JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

How do i change the focus to be on a different field, such as a JButton? Or remove focusing on anything all together? Currently when my application loads, it is picking (what appears to be) a random JTextField to set focus to!

I've tried

```
text.setFocusable(true);
text.requestFocusInWindow();
text.requestFocus(true);
text.requestFocus();
```

but no luck here. I've also tried [How to UnFocus a JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773132/how-to-unfocus-a-jtextfield) but i haven't had any luck with this working either.

The reason why I would like to not focus on the JTextFields is to avoid the hints from not appearing when the application first loads.

As you can see from the image, there is no hint on one of the JTextFields...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `requestFocusInWindow` is the prefered method for component to ask for focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason why I would like to not focus on the JTextFields is to avoid the hints from not appearing when the application first loads

[Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) can support this requirement (ie. the prompt will disappear only when text is entered). Then you don't have to worry if the text field has focus or not.

> How do i change the focus to be on a different field, such as a JButton?

You would use `requestFocusInWindow()` on the component AFTER the GUI is visible.  But this doesn't make sense since the user would need to tab backwards to get to the text field. Or you could use the `RequestFocusListener` found in [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/). Again remember advanced users don't use the mouse.