# Calling JFrame and reprompting the same JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like add a simple code that will call the JFrame from the same package if its fullfill the if statement and if not it'll reprompt the same JFrame. thanks.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    login lg = new login(username,password);
    boolean isMatches = lg.checkUser();
    if(isMatches) {
        Welcome WEL = new Welcome(); // How to call the Welcome JFrame
        WEL.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
        // How to make it reprompt the same JFrame?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use multiple `JFrame` instead you can use `CardLayout` and can switch between different views.

The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel instances) that share the *same display space*.

See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and find a [Demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/index.html#CardLayoutDemo) as well.

For more info read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: Since a log-in panel is typically much smaller than a main GUI, it is well suited to a (possibly) modal dialog or a `JOptionPane`.  An [e.g of the latter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10773412/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes I agree with you and for other views we can use JPanel.

Comment: True.  And even if using a dialog in this instance for the log-in itself, you might use a `CardLayout` to flip from a 'splash' style image in the main UI before log-in, to the GUI proper after log-in.